# Givinig range in relationship for entity model in .NET Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, dbcontext, code-first

I have two models with the relationship as below (i.e 1 to 1-3). i.e model class A has at least one but not more than 3 instance/record of class B. How will I specify this relationship?

[image]

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<B> bbs{ get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public A aa { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: EF - nor even SQL - supports this kind of constraint right-off-the-bat. Some quantifier-constraints are possible (by using a `CHECK` constraint to enforce an upper-bound value on a `UNIQUE` column) but it is _impossible_ to set a lower-bound on a quantifier, simply because you would have to violate it when you start `INSERT`ing records. (also known as the "chicken-and-egg problem" in SQL - some systems support Deferrable Constraints but most don't. The only way to make headway here is by programming directly in SQL, by-hand - but I see you're using EF Code-First - I'd say you're SOL.

Comment: What did you mean by SOL ?

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shit%20outta%20luck

Comment: Or for a more reputable reference source: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shit_out_of_luck#English

Comment: Out of curiosity, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Using SQL Server